# Symbolic space and Bernoulli Product measure

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\Sigma=\{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $A$ be the sigma-algebra generated by the cylinders sets $\{w∈Ω|∀s∈S,w_s=ϵ_s\}$
with $S⊂\mathbb{N}$
finite and $ϵ_s∈\{0,1\}$
. Let $p∈(0,1)$
. We take product measure with density $p$
on $(Ω,A)$
:$μ=∏_{n∈\mathbb{N}}μ_n$
where $μ_n$
is Bernoulli measure on $\{0,1\}$
given by $μ_n(w_n=1)=p$
, $μ_n(w_n=2)=1-p$.

Let $\mu_{1/2}$ be the corresponding product measure if we choose $p=1/2$.

Let $\mathbf{i}=(i_1,i_2,\dots)\in \Sigma$.

Let $\mathbf{i}|_n = (i_1,...,i_n)$, $n \in \mathbb {N}$.

For $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, define
\begin{equation*}
    ||\mathbf{i}|_n||_j := \text{Number of occurrences of}~~ j ~~\text{in}~ (i_1,\dots,i_n),~j=1,2.
\end{equation*}

Then $||\mathbf{i}|_n||_1+||\mathbf{i}|_n||_2=n.$

Set $x_n^{\mathbf{i}}=~||\mathbf{i}|_n||_1-||\mathbf{i}|_n||_2 
 =~2 ||\mathbf{i}|_n||_1-n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $A=\{\mathbf{i}\in \Sigma:~ \text{The sequence}~~(x_n^{\mathbf{i}})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}~~\text{is bounded above} \}$ $\subset \Sigma$.

**Question:** What is  $\mu_{1/2}(A)$ ?

**Conjecture:** $\mu_{1/2}(A)=1$.

Any reference to Bernoulli product measure and Symbolic space is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Being a Bernoulli product measure means that the Random variables $\{ i_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d . That means that any string with positive probability of concurring will occur. Since $p$ and $1-p$ are both non-zero, any string has a positive probability of occurring.

Since you can write $A=\cup_{m\in \mathbb{N}} A_m$ where $A_m:=\{ \mathbf{i}\in \Sigma:~ x_n^{\mathbf{i}}\leq m \; \text{for all} \; n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, and $\mu(A_m^c)=1$, you get that $\mu(A)=0$.